# Estimated copy time?

Tags: macos, usb, file-transfer

Copying Finder folders of JPEGs from new iMac 10.11.5 to new SanDisk 256GB flash drive, USB 3.0.

129 GB is taking three hours. Seems slow to me, does this sound right?

Comment: Without more information it's hard to diagnose however it does sound like there's no issue here since copy a ton (like 130GB ton!) of individual small files takes far longer than one huge file due to the way file systems are setup

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the write speed of your flash drive. But it does sound right since (like Sirens pointed out) it's many small files and not one big one.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. But a related question (that I posted separately but didn't get any answers) -- any idea why copying to an encrypted disk image on that same flash drive takes 10 or 20 times longer?  I.e., copying 12 GB of music takes 10 minutes, but 2-3 hours to an encrypted disk image.

Comment: just a simple guess but the encryption's gonna take time so i think it's logical... although maybe not 10-20 times longer...